# bash script for deleting kubernetes pods with no resources

Tags: kubernetes

I would appreciate if anybody can help me with a bash script that can determine kubernetes namespace that has no resources inside and then delete the namespace completely.

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate if anybody can help me with a bash script

I am not going to write the bash script for you, but I will try help you for sure.

Every namespace, even freshly created has some resources in it.
No namespace is ever empty.

Have a look:

```
➜  ~ kubectl create ns asd
namespace/asd created

➜  ~ kubectl api-resources | grep true | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {}: ; kubectl get {} -n asd"
bindings:
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
configmaps:
NAME               DATA   AGE
kube-root-ca.crt   1      4m36s
endpoints:
No resources found in asd namespace.
events:
No resources found in asd namespace.
limitranges:
No resources found in asd namespace.
persistentvolumeclaims:
No resources found in asd namespace.
pods:
No resources found in asd namespace.
podtemplates:
No resources found in asd namespace.
replicationcontrollers:
No resources found in asd namespace.
resourcequotas:
No resources found in asd namespace.
secrets:
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-fh98f   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      22s
serviceaccounts:
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
default   1         22s
services:
No resources found in asd namespace.
controllerrevisions:
No resources found in asd namespace.
daemonsets:
No resources found in asd namespace.
deployments:
No resources found in asd namespace.
replicasets:
No resources found in asd namespace.
statefulsets:
No resources found in asd namespace.
localsubjectaccessreviews:
Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource
horizontalpodautoscalers:
No resources found in asd namespace.
cronjobs:
No resources found in asd namespace.
jobs:
No resources found in asd namespace.
leases:
No resources found in asd namespace.
endpointslices:
No resources found in asd namespace.
events:
No resources found in asd namespace.
ingresses:
No resources found in asd namespace.
ingresses:
No resources found in asd namespace.
networkpolicies:
No resources found in asd namespace.
poddisruptionbudgets:
No resources found in asd namespace.
rolebindings:
No resources found in asd namespace.
roles:
No resources found in asd namespace.
```

Notice that there is always a default service account, and even if you delete it, it will be recreated automatically. Same applies to kube-root-ca.crt configmap, and default token secret.

Therefore your script should loop over every other resource and check if empty, but in these three cases I mentioned above you can't just check if namesapce is empty, you should check if the namespace has only these default resources before you delete it.

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: yes Matt it is helpful. thanks a lot.